# How to read an array consists of files in c++

Tags: c++

I need to read files one by one, from one group of files in my folder.
Is it possible to use ifstream from c++ library but, instead full file name like 
ifstream myfile("file.txt"), I plan to use some string variable which contains each file's name. All names of files I would put in some new file from which my c++ class object could read.

Thanks,
Vlada

Comment: `ifstream myfile(fileName.c_str())`? Not sure I understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
std::ifstream listoffilenames("filenames");

std::string  name;
while(std::getline(listoffilenames, name))  // Assume the file contains 1 name per line.
{

    std::ifstream file(name.c_str());       // Open the file name you just read.
                                            // Now you can read from it like normal.
    // READ file
}
```